# CURL - While Loop until Captcha is sucesss?

Tags: php, curl, captcha

Assume captcha key is invalid, it need to download new captcha image again and re-validate captcha key. How can that be done?

I have include short example, is this the way to do?

```
while (1) {
    $postData = http_build_query($data);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "\**********************.crt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://domain.com/test" . $form_link);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiesPath . "/cookiefile.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiesPath . "/cookiefile.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $page = curl_exec($ch);

    //Just a quick example
    if ($page == "Sucess") {
       break;
    } else {
        $ch = curl_init();
        //Some curl code here to Re-download Captcha Image (new image)
        $data['captchaText'] = CaptchaToText::Scan("images/captcha.jpg");
    }
}
```

Comment: It got nothing to do with spam!

Comment: Why the second curl_init inside the else clause? Curl handles can be reused, so there's no need to init a new one each iteration, let alone two, one of which is immediately trashed by the second one.

Comment: By definition, you can not solve a CAPTCHA automatically - otherwise, it wouldn't be a `Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart`.

Comment: @Marc B, ah good point.. So im on the right path? If captcha is invalid and then will loop again and again until `$page == "Sucess"`

Comment: @phihag The definition needs to be updated then. Captcha's have been broken for a long time (not to mention there are tons of services sitting many people in call centers to fill them out over API's such as these).

Comment: @John Cartwright People in call centers filling out CAPTCHAs don't break a CAPTCHA scheme; they are showing that the scheme is working as intended, as it *tells Computers and Humans Apart*. Also, note that an `automatically solvable CAPTCHA` is an oxymoren. CAPTCHA schemes can be broken though, and there is almost certainly no CAPTCHA that can't be beaten by pure luck.

Comment: @phihag: CAPTCHA is a catch-phrase these days. there's plenty of amateur text-mangling schemes that ARE captchas, but are trivially solveable by OCR, because the actual mangling is useless for OCR prevention purposes. In other words, there's plenty of captchas that are outright useless, because they ARE automatically solveable.

Comment: @phihag My point was captchas have been automatically solvable for a long time with OCR. As someone who knew nothing about OCR, I was able to break most CAPTCHA (google, yahoo, etc) in about a week. I only mentioned call centers solving captchas to solidify my point that captcha's are essentially dated and are generally more of a nuisance than a security feature.

Comment: Is this post related to web parsing where form is secured with Google CAPTCHA ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you doing it right. But only in the firs part )

You already have cURL resource initiated ($ch).

So you only need to execute cURL request again by curl_exec($ch) and you will get a new page.
All the cURL options set by curl_setopt() are saved in resourse.

Here is the code:

```
if ($page == "Sucess") {
   break;
} else {
    $page = curl_exec($ch);
    //Some curl code here to Re-download Captcha Image (new image)
    $data['captchaText'] = CaptchaToText::Scan("images/captcha.jpg");
}
```